# PowerQuery merge tables result not in default order

Tags: excel, powerpivot, powerquery

I am merging two tables in Excel using PowerQuery and everything works fine except the results (from merged table) are not in order of the default data (common column).

Table 1 is simply policy number while the table 2 contains different size and has some data I am trying to lookup. Policy numbers are sorted by PFLxxx (smallest to largest) then BFLxxx (smallest to largest). Results from merged table are only sorting by PFL or BFL so I can't get my results in the same order of my default data (policy number).

[image: Result from Merge Table]
[image: Default Policy Number]

Comment: You could add an ID number and then [sort the table within PowerQuery](https://support.office.com/article/sort-a-table-power-query-baf200d5-1097-49cf-80b3-f1ce07b5f114#__toc354843383)

Comment: Is anything preventing you from sorting the columns however you'd like after merging?

Comment: thanks, if I added the ID column for table 1, and after merging, I can just sort it by ID column then my results are the way I need it to be. Originally it will only sort it alphabetically.